# Similar code. One works another not? Why?

Tags: swiftui

I cannot find the issue. Please help.
There are 2 pages. First is working perfectly and the sheet (AnalysisGraph) is working
On second is not. Data is not changed and empty data is passed to (AnalysisGraph or ShowGraph - ShowGraph is like AnalysisGraph only without function)
Why in 1 page I can change data in saveAnalysis and passed that to AnalysisGraph but I cannot change data in 2 page?

Sorry for long code

1 page

```
@State var analizaId = ""
@State var finance = 0.0
@State var value = 0.0
@State var growth = 0.0

                .sheet(isPresented: $newAnalysis) {
                    AnalysisGraph(clearAnalysis: clear, analizaId: analizaId, finance: finance, value: value, growth: growth, name: name, notes: notes)
                }
            }

 private func saveAnalysis(){
        finance = model.financeCondition()
        growth = model.growthCondition()
        value = model.valueCondition()

        analizaId = model.modelId
 }
```

2 page

```
@State var analizaId = ""
@State var finance = 0.0
@State var value = 0.0
@State var growth = 0.0

           .sheet(isPresented: $showAnalysisGraph) {
                ShowGraph(analizaId: analizaId, finance:     finance, value: value, growth: growth, name: name, notes: notes)
```

}

```
private func setDataToGraph(){
    if let idAnalysis = selected{
        for (_, item) in analysisList.enumerated(){
            if let idItem = item.id{
                if idItem == idAnalysis{
                    thisAnaliza = item
                }
            }
        }
    }
    if let showAnaliza = thisAnaliza, let idOptionalAnaliza =    selected, let idAnaliza = idOptionalAnaliza{
        print("idAnaliza: \(idAnaliza)")
        analizaId = idAnaliza
        finance = showAnaliza.financeAnalysis
        growth = showAnaliza.growthAnalysis
        value = showAnaliza.valueAnalysis
        name = showAnaliza.name ?? "No Name"
        notes = showAnaliza.notes ?? "No notes"
        print("analizaId: \(analizaId)")
        print("\(finance)")
        print("\(value)")
        print("\(growth)")
        print(name)
        print(notes)
        showAnalysisGraph.toggle()
    }
}
```

Comment: Is this a [mre]? Is *all* of the code here necessary to reproduce the issue?

Comment: I would focus on the "minimal" rather than "complete" in this case. Yes, this is a lot of code, and it's very unclear what you've changed between them. To debug this, start with the working code and evolve it one step at a time to the non-working code to discover at what point it fails. As a starting point, there are many TextFields here. Does a single TextField demonstrate the problem? Etc. Simplify to the smallest change that breaks, and you probably won't even need to ask the question (but we're here if you do).

Comment: Ok I will cut it. I hope that short code will  be able to show my problem. Regarding debugging yes I did that. I spend a lot of time on it. The problem is that on one page I can change value of analizaId finance value etc and pass new value to view in sheet and it is working but on second page after I change values of analizaId finance value etc function in sheet doesn't get new values. Please look now on my code and help me if you can

Comment: As mentioned, show a minimal reproducible code that produces your issue, see: [minimal code](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example). I suspect/guess (since you don't show enough code), that using, `.sheet(item: ...)` instead would solve your problem.

Comment: Thanks workingdog support Ukraine YEAH!. Item will not work I need isPresented. Finally I make my 2 page working. Sheet is not working but .navigationDestination is! Why? First Page is NavigationStack ScrollView Form and .sheet is working. Second page NavigationStack List and .sheet is not working but .navigationDestination is OK. I don't understand. I have more projects and I would like to use NavStack with List and .sheet. (maybe it is issue with macOS only -that project is on macOS and maybe there is issue?)

Answer (score 1):

In 2 page, body is only called when states are set if those previous states have been read inside body. Inside sheet doesn't count.

Try replacing the 4 states with 1 optional item struct state (encapsulating your 4 vars) and use sheet(item:).